# Comparing Dates Only on DateTime/DateTimeOffset Objects

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimeoffset

I receive a DateTime from the client: `DateTime CurrentTimeOnClient`
I have a DateTimeOffset I get from the db: `DateTimeOffset DateTimeOffsetFromDb`

**I need to compare the two dates, IGNORING the time AND time zone.** In other words, I just want the raw date from both objects. I tried using `FooDateTimeOffset.DateTime.Date` but it seems to still factor in the time, so what I have now is this:

```
DateTimeOffset clientDateTimeOffSet = DateTime.SpecifyKind(CurrentTimeOnClient, DateTimeKind.Utc);
clientDateTimeOffSet = await RemoveTimeComponentFromDateTimeOffset(clientDateTimeOffSet);
clientDateTimeOffSet = await SetTimeZoneOffsetToZero(clientDateTimeOffSet);
```

And the helper methods:

```
public async Task<DateTimeOffset> SetTimeZoneOffsetToZero(DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffSetObj)
{
    TimeSpan zeroOffsetTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    return dateTimeOffSetObj.ToOffset(zeroOffsetTimeSpan);
}

public async Task<DateTimeOffset> RemoveTimeComponentFromDateTimeOffset(DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffSetObj)
{
    DateTime dateWithZeroedTime = new DateTime(dateTimeOffSetObj.Year, dateTimeOffSetObj.Month, dateTimeOffSetObj.Day, 0, 0, 0);
    return dateWithZeroedTime; 
}
```

Then I clean the DateTimeOffset obj from the db in the same way (though obviously without the need to convert them) and compare them.

```
bool foo = dateFromDb > dateFromClient;
```

P.S. I am aware that these questions HAVE been answered separately, but I would like to see if I made any glaring mistakes or if I am overdoing it. (but again, the suggested `.Date` solution doesn't seem to work).

Edit: @James

```
    //TESTING
    var testDateAndTime = new DateTimeOffset(2008, 5, 1, 8, 6, 32,new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
    //This is just some db object that has a date field that I had on hand
    var anncmnt = db.Announcements.First(a => a.Id == 13);

    //CLEAN TIME AND DATE
    testDateAndTime = testDateAndTime.DateTime.Date; 

    anncmnt.EndDate = testDateAndTime;
    await db.SaveChangesAsync(); 
    //TESTING
```

Db Result: `2008-05-01 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00`

Comment: Why are those methods `async`?  Without any `await` statements that's just going to run synchronously.

Comment: Our API is async, so we make helpers async in case we need to use them with async endpoints. These run synchronously (default if await isn't used) as far as I know.

Comment: But there's no point in making something `async` if it isn't.  It'll just give anyone using your API the impression that it is.

Comment: There was something about trying to use sync helpers with async endpoints that didn't mesh. I will look into it and reply with details. Might take me a bit though. I could just be wrong too.

Comment: Can you be more clear about the issue you see with the Date method?  How does it not, "seem to work"?

Comment: @JamesFegan Ignore this question for a little bit. I will retest the Date method. What was happening before was it still accounting for the timezone offset, instead of giving me zero time and zero offset. I could be entirely wrong. I will let you know.

Comment: Thanks for the test code above.  I updated my answer using your testDateAndTime value.  It looks like there is a static method that solves your problem.  You can reconstruct a new DateTime object from the old but specify it as UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot UTC.  Try using the SpecifyKind method.  It appears to give what you need and passes my quick unit test below:

```
        //TESTING
        for (var hr = 0; hr < 24; hr++)
        {
            var testDateAndTime = new DateTimeOffset(2008, 5, 1, hr, 6, 32, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
            var noOffsetDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(testDateAndTime.Date, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            Console.WriteLine(noOffsetDate);
        }
```

Comment: Basically, your answer clears the time, but not the timezone offset. So when I get it from db, it adjusts time for timezone offset, which can throw off date.

Comment: James, that seems to work, thank you. I thought that this would change the date or time (rather than just setting offset, it would CONVERT to UTC, if you know what I mean). Looks like I am wrong though. I will test more thoroughly and definitely come back to accept the answer.

Comment: Great.  I would consider this a 'buyer-beware' sort of answer though.  You're losing information with this conversion as the Date field was only accurate when examined with the original time/offset context.  In this case, I'm assuming that you have some reason to know ahead of time that the time/offset information from the DB is invalid or irrelevant and could be safely truncated.  Test cases from your DB with DateTimes close to midnight (within the offset span) would help root out the truth of that.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

That is weird that the .Date() doesn't work. This is something I've done in the past when addressed with an issue like this. I parse the datetime date string then compare. So I do the below code.

```
dateFromDb = DateTime.Parse(dateFromDb.ToShortDateString());
dateFromClient= DateTime.Parse(dateFromClient.ToShortDateString());
```

Then try comparing it and see if that works?

Comment: That seems like a viable option as a last resort.